# MapInfo 10.5.1 Update and MS Access Database

Tags: mapinfo, vba, ms-access

I am having problems with a database that I have developed. The data uses MapInfo for any of the spatial parts of it.

I installed the update to MapInfo 10.5.1 and I now get an error when I 
am trying to access an ADODB.recordset. object which previously 
worked. I get the error:

Method 'Connection' of object '_CurrentProject' failed

when the database tries to run the code:

```
rs5.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
```

(where rs5 is a ADODB.Recordset):

Has anyone else seen anything like this? Is this related to the 
updated drivers for Office 2010 that were installed with the update? I 
am using Access 2007. The database still works on machines that are 
10.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the install Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 2.8 SP1 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=78cac895-efc2-4f8e-a9e0-3a1afbd5922e&displaylang=en

Comment: Should I be concerned about installing something from 2005 when my version of office is 2007, and it seems the MapInfo update installed drivers for 2010. Or will this not affect either of these things?